# How to freeze a Keras graph with BatchNorm layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to load a frozen Keras Graph with Batchnorm layers, but getting the error:

```
Message: TensorFlow.TFException : Input 0 of node
DenseNet/DenseBlock/ConvBlock/dense_0_0_bn/cond/ReadVariableOp/Switch was
passed float from DenseNet/DenseBlock/ConvBlock/dense_0_0_bn/gamma:0
incompatible with expected resource.
```

Normally the solution to this is to do: [keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11032#issuecomment-429989228), however when loading the graph in another API (for instance TensorflowSharp / TfLite) this isn't an option (as far as I can tell).

Here's how I'm currently saving the graph:

```
def freeze_session(session, keep_var_names=None, output_names=None, clear_devices=True):

    from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants
    import tensorflow as tf

    graph = session.graph
    with graph.as_default():
        freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
        output_names = output_names or []
        output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.global_variables()]
        # Graph -> GraphDef ProtoBuf
        input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
        if clear_devices:
            for node in input_graph_def.node:
                node.device = ""

        for node in input_graph_def.node:
            if node.op == 'RefSwitch':
                for index in range(len(node.input)):
                    if 'moving_' in node.input[index]:
                        node.input[index] = node.input[index] + '/read'
            elif node.op == 'AssignSub':
                node.op = 'Sub'
                if 'use_locking' in node.attr: del node.attr['use_locking']

        frozen_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(session, input_graph_def,
                                                      output_names, freeze_var_names)
        return frozen_graph
```

Is there any way I can programmatically remove the Batchnorm layers before saving so that I can load the model in an environment outside Keras?